# Permanently overriding underscan default for HDMI output from ATI video cards

Tags: hdmi, amd-graphics-card

I recently bought a new LCD monitor.  It has an HDMI input, but no DVI.  I've used the included DVI-to-HDMI adapter to connect it to my video card.  I've found that the ATI drivers by default apply a 8% underscan to HDMI outputs, which with the adapter is how the output is recognized.  That results in both a blurry output and part of the screen unused.

While I know already that I can change this through Catalyst Control Center, the problem is that even when I use the same resolution and refresh rate for games, the screen resets and I have to alt-tab into windows, open CCC and set the underscan back to 0%.

Is there any registry setting that can be set to permanently have it default to a 0% underscan whenever it changes video modes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Overscan/Underscan settings without Catalyst Control Center](http://superuser.com/questions/458321/change-overscan-underscan-settings-without-catalyst-control-center)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, but overscan instead of underscan - change the dvi to hdmi adapter, as this was the cause of my problem. (I bought a belkin adapter and this works for me now.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posted a long time ago, but maybe someone will find my answer useful anyway! ;-) 
I found this solution elsewhere in this forum, and it worked great on my Win 7 PC with an AMD HD7750 Graphic card:

```
Go to the following key in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\video{####....}\0000

Create a new DWORD:

"DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan" = dword 0x0000


Note: there might be several {####....} , should be the one with most of the 
ATI settings.
```

I had the problem when connecting my PC to my Panasonic TV, but I think this happens with AMD/ATI graphics cards when connected via HDMI weather it be a TV or an LCD screen...