# Upscaling or stretch resolution to fit tv screen on Windows 10

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, windows-10, resolution, scaling

I have a laptop with an AMD Mobility Radeon HD 4500 graphics card that output a maximum resolution of 1366 x 768. On Windows 8 I used to use AMD Catalyst's scaling option to make the HDMI output fit my TV screen. Unfortunately, I believe AMD have dropped support for my card and Catalyst no longer works on my Windows 10 laptop after I upgraded, I tried installing the latest Catalyst software from AMD but it seems that it fails to install and does not support my card.

I like to know if there is a way to upscale the resolution to fit my screen as now it shows on my TV with a thick black border. I was wondering if there is a native way on Windows to do that? I am also game for a third party application if anyone knows about one that works on Windows 10.

Comment: I know you asked for windows native, but have you tried using the upscaling features of you TV (e.g. wide, zoom, stretch etc)? Also, if I recall correctly, if you set the laptop to single-display mode (not clone) and have the HDMI as the sole output, you may be able to select the TV's native resolution

Comment: @Yorik The TV upscale helps a little bit, my TV only has two options (native and wide) changing to wide upscales a little bit yet it does not fill the screen and there is a significant amount of unused screen. As for switching to a single output, I'm afraid it does not help even though both the display configuration options in Settings and Control Panel report the resolution to be 1920x1080

Comment: hmm. so even at 1920 resolution, you get black bars? Perhaps this is due to the overscan setting? IIRC, AMD defaults to a minor overscan correction when connected via HDMI. ( http://superuser.com/questions/458321/change-overscan-underscan-settings-without-catalyst-control-center )

Comment: @Yorik unfortunately this did not work, I still get the bars even though I've been fiddling with registry keys for about a day now and restarted my computer a dozen times or so but it seems this no longer works with Win10